# Range based for loop through non-const literal c++

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++11, casting, constants

Compiler context: I am compiling with `GDB v8.3 Ubuntu` with options `g++ -Im -O2 -std=c++0x`.

Very frequently I need to complete some loop for two or three objects so I use wrap the expression in a range based for loop with a containing litteral.

In Python3 this would look like:

```py
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]

for v in (a,b):
    func(v)
```

In c++ this obviously isn't so simple. As far as I am aware, using `{a,b}` creates some type of initializer list, therefor casting does not properly work. In my attempts I come to something of this sort, but do no understand how I would properly **pass by reference and also have it be mutable**, as my compiler complains this is neccessarily const.

```cpp
vector<int> a {1,2,3};
vector<int> b {4,5,6};

for(auto& v: {a,b}) // error non-const
    func(v);
```

Comment: Is `v` supposed to be each `vector` or every `int` in the joined vectors?

Comment: To be clear, you want that to be equivalent to `func(a); func(b);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int x,y;
for(int& i:{std::ref(x),std::ref(y)}){
    i=7;
}
```

`auto&` won't work, and you do have to repeat `std::ref` for each element.

Another trick is:

```
auto action=[&](auto&foo){
  // code
};
action(v1);
action(v2);
```

You can write:

```
void foreach_arg(auto&&f, auto&&...args){
  ((void)f(decltype(args)(args)),...);
}
```

or pre-[c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) versions in more characters, then:

```
auto action=[&](auto&foo){
  // code
};
foreach_arg(action, v1, v2);
```

If you want the arguments mentioned first, you can do:

```
auto foreacher(auto&&...args){
  return [&](auto&&f){
    ((void)f(decltype(args)(args)),...);
  };
}
```

and get:

```
foreacher(v1,v2)([&](auto&v){
  // loop body
});
```

apologies for any typos.  Just writing insomnia-code, untested as yet.

`decltype` thing is a short `std::forward` equivalent in this case (with `auto&&` args; with some other declarations it doesn't work).

`auto` arguments to functions are a [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) thing.

Then`,...` is comma-fold execute, a [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) thing.

`auto` arguments to lambdas are a [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) thing.

All can be replaced with [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) constructs (in this case) at the cost of a lot more verbosity.

Answer (score 4):

Based on your python program, it appears that you want to iterate through all the vectors, but with a mutable reference to each vector. You can do this by using pointers:

```
for(auto *v: {&a, &b})  // iterate over pointers to the vectors
    func(*v);           // dereference the pointers to get mutable
                        // references to the vectors
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zc4oEf).